# "message not found" error in aiogram when i try to edit the message

Tags: python, function, callback, aiogram, message-handlers

`I have a telegram bot that, when pressing the inline "select" button, changes the reply markup of this message (removes the "select" button so that the user does not spam it) and sends the user a new message with an inline "cancel" button. When the user clicks the "cancel" button , the markup in the previous message is changed (the "select" button is returned), and the message with the "cancel" button is deleted.

[Before pressing the "Select" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1uFE.png)
[After pressing the "Select" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV1h6.png)
[After pressing the "Cancel" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPlXd.png)`

`(Keyboards)`

```
call = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='select', callback_data='cll')
        ], [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='back', callback_data='bl')
        ]
    ]
)

call1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='back', callback_data='bl')
        ]
    ]
)

cancel = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    inline_keyboard=[
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='cancel', callback_data='off')
        ]
    ]
)
```

`(main code)`

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def C(message: Message):
    await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id, reply_markup=call1)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='You selected it', reply_markup=cancel)


@dp.message_handler()
async def D(message: Message):
    await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id - 1,
                                        reply_markup=call)  # As far as I understand, the problem is in this message
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def reaction(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    match callback.data:
        case 's1':
            await callback.message.edit_text('Theme1', reply_markup=call)
        case 'cll':
            await C(message=callback.message)
        case 'off':
            await D(message=callback.message)
```

`When I press "cancel" for the first time, everything works. When I try to repeat this whole cycle (I press "select" and then "cancel" 2nd time) - an error occurs:

aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToEditNotFound: Message to edit not found

As far as I understand, the problem is in the tagged command (bot.edit_message_reply_markup) for some reason he does not see the previous message. And the 1st time it works, but the 2nd time it doesn't. Please tell me what's wrong?`

Comment: Any solutions? I got the same error.